The direct consequences for Adam & Eve due to the fall
I was going through Genesis and taking note of the direct consequences for Adam and Eve in the narrative. Fittingly, I identified 7 - which I list below. I'm curious how my interpretation compares with Jewish schools of thought. Did I miss any consequences? How do you interpret their symbolic significance?


Banishment. Literally from the Garden, symbolically from God's presence.
Shame / Guilt. Literally knowledge of their nakedness that brings shame. Symbolically, the shame / guilt of their sin - which leads man to love the darkness rather than have his misdeeds exposed.
Death. Literally the (eventual) death of the body, symbolically a spiritual death - for though they were made to be sons of God, they have chosen to live contrary to his ways and follow their own desires.
Hard Labor. Literally man must engage in physical hard labor in order to survive. Not only is there no rain or steady seasons, but now there are thorns and such to further aggravate the situation. Symbolically, this is a denial of the rest found with God.
Servitude. Literally woman is now subjugated to man - the loss of equality. For, it says, a woman's desire shall be for her husband. Symbolically, this represents our enslavement to sin - to those passions which ensnare us and master us.
Pain. Literally, woman's birth pains are greatly increased. Offhand, I think symbolically this represents the increased difficulty of being born of God - the internal struggle between the desires of the flesh vs the desire to do what is right. With knowledge comes responsibility and accountability.
War. Literally, enmity between the offspring of Eve and of the serpent. Symbolically, the conflict between the sons of God and the sons of Satan; between the righteous and the sinful world at large.


Each one of these consequences is discussed at great length in the sources. Even if you were to split the question into 7 parts, I still think they might be closed for "lack of focus", as "How do you interpret their symbolic significance?" is, as I've said, something we'd have books worth of discussions and opinions! Is there any way you can focus the question a bit?

@RabbiKaii That's fair - but then most topics in theology can have books written on them in isolation :) It's also possible to give an overview of one's interpretation as I did above.

I feel there are 15 questions here: 1) Are these the only consequences? and for each of the 7, Is this symbolism correct/sourced? and are there other sources with different interpretations of the symbolism?. Can you think of any ways of making it more focussed? Maybe make this questions just 1), and then make 7 separate questions for the other two questions for each (and maybe instead of asking for all other sources, ask if people would be bring one or two other sources)

See Pirkei Rabbi Eliezer chapter 14

@RabbiKaii well I wasn't expecting any individual to list all interpretations
